# adodb connection erroring during open of recordset

Tags: ms-access, vb6, connection, adodb

Using VB6 & ADODB to open access 2000 DB. Connection string opens. I verify this by getting the .STATE of the connection before opening recordset.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  With conn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
         & "Data Source=C:\Path to database\MyDb.mdb;"
  End With
  conn.Open

  Debug.Print conn.ConnectionString
End Sub
```

The below snippet shows the line where the error occurs

```
Private Sub btnGO_Click()
Dim strDbName As String
Dim strg As String
Dim chkr As Variant
Dim MyCnt As Integer

chkr = False

Dim strsql As String
strsql = "Select * from [dbo].[BidItem]"

With rst
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Source = "Select * from [dbo].[BidItem]"
    .Open   -------------------------------------> Errors at this point
End With


With rst
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        MyCnt = .RecordCount
    End If
End With

MsgBox ("open")
MsgBox ("Count of TableRows: " & MyCnt)
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Exact error message is `Run-Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual\VB98\dbo.mdb'`

Comment: Exact error message is
Run-Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual\VB98\dbo.mdb'.

Comment: Without giving away any login information, what is in your conn connection string?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `[dbo].` qualifier and just use `SELECT * FROM [BidItem]`?

Comment: Does Access know anything about dbo?  Have you tried it with 'select * from biditem'?

Comment: Thanks All. The "dbo." was there because the access DB was linked to a SQL DB. I disconnected the links and removed the "dbo.". I was able to access the Access Db. I then added the links back and was still able to access the SQL DB through the Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

Both your snippets are coded as 'Private' which means they don't share well.  You 'Go' button isn't clear on what the actual 'ActiveConnection' was set to be earlier in the Form load.